# IBM Watson Assistant, how can I remove multiple items from an array?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, watson-assistant

I have a list `unmentioned_colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"]`
If I mention multiple colors, I want to update my unmentioned_colors array, removing the ones that I mentioned. So if I write "red green" I want to remove them from unmentioned_colors where it will become ["blue", "yellow"]

I tried
unmentioned_colors = `"<? $unmentioned_colors.removeValue(@colors.values) ?>"`
But it is not working.
How can I remove multiple @colors from my array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove all `@colors` items from `$unmentioned_colors` one should set a context variable `$_bool_listchanged` as shown here:

`_bool_listchanged = "<? $unmentioned_colors.removeAll(@colors.values) ?>"` .

This solution does not require a loop and works because underneath the hood Watson Assistant uses Java to manipulate items in the contact. So on this array we have the method removeAll which we can call from Java.

Answer (score 1):

Watson Assistant supports [two methods to remove an item from a JSONArray](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-methods.html#arrays), remove (using the index) and removeValue (using the value). Each method removes exactly one element. So you would need to loop / iterate over the elements to delete and then invoke the method. Could you process this in the app?

Another approach is to look into [SpEL (the expression language)](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/expression-language.html#evaluation-syntax) and work with collection selection / projection.

Comment: One could process this client side but it becomes very specific and unmaintainable. Because it would have to be hard coded to a specific node ID or phrase. One could build a looping node in on the Watson side, but that would mess up flow logic. I need the solution to work in a context statement. The solution that I posted below is the best that I can find.

I looked into SpEL but saw no clear way to filter or eliminate values.